# landlord having neighbor stalk the property

Tags: rental-property, landlord, tenant, wisconsin

We recently rented a house and the day we moved in we were told the neighbor will do the yard work and take care of the home. Also in the lease the landlord should give 24 hour notice before appearance but nothing about this neighbor we didn't know about. Nowhere in the lease does it say someone would do the yard work.

The problem is the neighbor has a couple domestic abuse charges in his past and he stays in the yard for hours looking in windows and snooping. No exaggeration - the first two weeks we moved in, the neighbor was in the yard at least 5 hours a day every day. We look out the window and the neighbor and some older man just standing outside looking at the house. The neighbor is a really large man about 6'5" and very creepy. We are always on edge and don't feel safe having him in the yard constantly.

We put up cameras to video tape the stalking. We have our own mower and can take care of the yard ourselves, but the landlord refuses and defends the neighbors actions. There is always a new excuse to have the neighbor enter the yard. Gutters, fertilizer, snow removal, always a new excuse. Always in the yard. We can't even go outside and we can do these things ourselves. Is there anything that can be done? We don't feel private or safe.

Comment: You can contact the police and report an unknown intruder, who claims to be an agent of the landlord acting illegally. Beyond that, appropriate solutions are likely to involve some kind of legal advice specific to your situation and jurisdiction.

Comment: The person isn't unknown but he is an agent of the landlord.

Comment: Even if they are, this is still acting illegally in almost every sensible jurisdiction with a tenancy law.

Answer (score 5):

Approach the neighbor in your yard and ask him to leave. You are the tenant, you have full rights to do so. Once he refuses to leave he is a trespasser and you can call the police to take care of him, let alone if he makes any threats.

Regarding the landlord, just ignore them and take care of the yard and the house as the lease terms bind you. Require them to give 24 hour notice before any appearance as the lease terms bind them.

Comment: Thank you.  Sounds simple. We can't continue to live like this and It would probably be best to have the police involved. The man has a history of violence against women even though the landlord swears he is a gentleman. I am afraid what will happen when I'm not home.

Comment: Might work. Doesn't solve the problem of what happens if 24 hour notice is given and then he still lingers. A protection order might also be needed. And, if the man is on probation or parole, a call to his probation or parole officer might be another way to address the problem. Also, if there is documentation of written demands and requests to the landlord, the landlord might very well have liability for negligent supervision if there was harm (cold comfort thought that might be), as the landlord is effectively ratifying the conduct.